# Rewrite every request with a web.config file in IIS

Tags: iis

I try to setup a web.config file that rewrites every request to a sub folder.

For example:

- http://www.example.com/index.html -> http://www.example.com/sub/index.html
- http://www.example.com/test/index.html -> http://www.example.com/test/sub/index.html

I need a way to add a folder in the middle or at the end of the url, depending on whether there is a file at the end or not. I tried something like this:

```
<rule name="to sub" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/sub/" />
</rule>
```

But this works only to folders, not for files. Any ideas or hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this is what you need:

```
<rule name="to sub" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)/(.*)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/sub/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```